# Como posso usar Django 1.9.6 dentro do meu ambiente virtual?

Tags: python, ubuntu, django-1.9, virtualenv

Estou tentando usar a versão 1.9.6 do django no ambiente virtual 'myvenv' que criei através do terminal do ubuntu, mas mesmo após ter feito a instalação através do comando `pip3 install django==1.9.6`, ao usar `python manage.py runserver` recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Engraçado que ao rodar `pip3 freeze` dentro do ambiente virtual vejo "Django==1.9.6" dentre os pacotes instalados e mesmo assim recebo o tal erro.

P.S: se, dentro do ambiente virtual, uso `sudo python manage.py runserver` não obtenho erro algum.

Comment: Estou assumindo que você estava *dentro* do ambiente virtual quando fez a instalação com pip, certo? (i.e. primeiro você usou o comando `source`, depois você usou o comando `pip3` para instalar o Django)

Comment: Tentou fazer a instalação do django pelo `apt-get`? eu costumo usar o proprio instalador da distro, já evitei muita dor de cabeça com isso

Comment: @BrumazziDB O problema é que o ambiente virtual usa seu próprio `site-packages` independente do ambiente global (e dependendo de como se criou o virtualenv, ele nem mesmo herda os pacotes instalados globalmente). Por isso instalar via `apt-get` não me parece uma boa ideia nesse contexto.

Comment: De fato, não faz mutio sentido usar a instalação do django via apt-get - a idéia de virtualenv's é justamente evitr os problemas que isso traz (para começar, você teria que ter um sistema operacional nos eu servidor que teria que ter exatamente  amesma versão do django que o seu s.o. de desenvolvimento - e assim por diante para todas as dependências de Python)

Comment: @mgibsonbr sim, já estava dentro do ambiente virtual

Comment: Certo... Acho deveria verificar a versão do python que está sendo chamada, muitas distros linux tem o python 2.x por padrão, se tentar `python3 manage.py runserver`, pode resolver

Comment: @BrumazziDB foi a primeira coisa que tentei quando o erro apareceu kkk. Tentei de tudo, mas até agora nada resolvido =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, no mínimo você está executando algum comando de fora do ambiente virtual ou está criando um ambiente virtual com a versão 2 do Python (aí pip3 será correspondente ao pip do seu sistema e não ao do seu ambiente).

Vou passar a receita completa de como se fazer o que você quer, assim elimina as possibilidades de dúvidas.

Primeiro de tudo é bom deixar claro que você **não** deve instalar o django com os pacotes do seu sistema. Tanto @jsbueno como @mgibsonbr e toda a literatura existente sobre django vão dizer para você criar a sua aplicação utilizando um ambiente virtual.

Em primeiro lugar você vai precisar do `virtualenv`. Este eu deixo você utilizar o do repositório do sistema. Instale a versão de acordo com a versão do Python que você quiser utilizar se você quiser facilitar sua vida, mas, na real, tanto faz.

Com ele instalado, crie uma pasta para o seu projeto e entre nela:

```
mkdir super_project
cd super_project
```

Crie um ambiente virtual:

```
virtualenv venv
```

Novamente, utilize a versão do virtualenv de acordo com a versão do Python que você deseja. No entanto, nada te impede de dizer ao virtualenv qual versão do Python você quer tomar como base:

```
virtualenv venv -p /usr/bin/python3
```

Independente da maneira, os dois comandos criarão uma pasta chamada `venv` dentro da pasta do seu projeto:

```
super_project
└── venv
```

Agora vem a etapa mais importante, ativar o ambiente virtual:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

Agora você pode instalar o que você quiser:

```
pip install django==1.9.6
```

Como a 1.9.6 é a última versão estável do django hoje, você não precisa tornar explícita a versão podendo apenas fazer:

```
pip install django
```

Com o django instalado, você pode começar a desenvolver sua aplicação:

```
django-admin startproject project
cd project
python manage.py runserver
```

E é isso.